# Can I omit const qualifiers in declaration for pointer types?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

For a function definition which contains the declaration of type `void foo(const int )` Both of the following declarations are valid.

```
void foo(const int); // valid
void foo(int); // valid, const can be omitted.
```

But if a function definition contains a declaration of type `void foo(const int*)` omitting const is ilegal:

```
void foo(const int *); // valid declaration
void foo(int *); // error: const cannot be omitted.
```

Why is `const` cannot be omitted in the function declaration if its parameter has pointer types? What makes the difference?

Comment: What is the error the compiler produces? The trivial counterexample to your assessment is int main(int argc, char **argv);

Comment: I use the syntax `int const n` and `int const * ptr` to emphasize what is going on. The `const` applies to the thing directly at its left, unless it's the first word in the type, in which case it applies to the thing directly on its right. When you say `const int * ptr`, that's the same as `int const * ptr`, which, when read right to left is: "ptr is a pointer to a const int". If you want to make the pointer itself `const`, you would say `int * const ptr`. "ptr is a const pointer to int". You can change the value at that memory address, but you cannot change which address you are pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only omit the const specifier when it's applied *directly* to the parameter. In the pointer case, it's applied to the thing being pointed at, not the pointer itself, so there's an extra level of indirection between const and the parameter. You could omit it in this case:

```
void foo(int* const);
void foo(int*);
```

Answer (score 3):

`const int x` means that `x` is read-only *inside* the function.  The outside world doesn't care either way; the function is working with a copy of the argument.

However `const int *p` means that `p` points to something that is read-only.  The outside world *does* care about this; it's a promise that the pointee can't be modified.

The corollary of this is that the following two declarations are equivalent:

```
void foo(const int *);
void foo(const int * const);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function deals with the copy of the passed argument. If that's integer, you can omit `const` as original will not be touched anyway. In case of the pointer to int type there are three options:

1. `int* p`
2. `const int* p` (or `int const* p`)
3. `const int* const p` (or `int const* const p`)

`const` can be applied to pointed object, pointer itself or to both. What you pass as an argument is pointer so you can omit `const` for it as its copy is passed to function. So (2) and (3) can be used interchangeably (only when used as function argument type!). But `const` for pointed object type makes difference:

- `void foo(const int* p);` // function cannot modify pointed integer object through p
- `void foo(int* p);`       // function can modify pointed integer object through p

In both cases function can modify `p` within function, but those changes are not reflected on the original pointer's value.